# Prove or disprove kernel($T$)∩range($T$)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $R$ and $T:V→V$ be a linear transformation s.t. $rank(T^2)=rank(T)$.

Prove or disprove $kernel(T)∩range(T)={0}$.

Thinking of $T$ with full rank, kernel(T) contains the zero vector only and range (T)=$V$ which suggests to me that the result holds good but what if $T$ doesn't have full rank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $v$ is in the range of $T$, then some $w$ satisfies $Tw=v$. Furthermore, if $v$ is also in the kernel of $T$, then $T^2 w = Tv=  0$. Even further,  if $v \ne 0$, then $w$ is in the kernel of $T^2$ but not in the kernel of $T$, so $\ker(T) \subsetneq \ker(T^2)$, and by rank-nullity, $\operatorname{rank}(T^2) < \operatorname{rank}(T)$.

Comment: @angryavian..really nice explanation..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k \ne 0$ and $k \in kernel(T) \cap range(T)$.

Let $k, k_1, \ldots, k_{n - 1}$ be basis for $T(V)$ and he has $n$ vectors.

Then basis for $T^2(V) \in <T(k_1), \ldots, T(k_n)>$ has $< n $ vectors.